# Creating my own custom Grease Pencil brushes using different facial textures in blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, grease-pencil

as soon as I have watched [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=3&v=abZxp-fHUSA) I've got an idea. As you can see on the tut,he created a grease pencil brush that has two caracteristics :
a pre-determined size and a pre-determined color and both these caracteristics have been chosen using krita. Now,I want to make something a little different. Instead of using a solid color to paint the texture,I want to use a facial texture,like this :

[image: facial]

the idea is to paint the head of my 3d character,trying to reach a better result than this :

[image: g]

I'm looking for an alternative to the projection painting with the stencil mode. This could give an advantage from my point of view : I can create different brushes,one for each head I want to use.

Also,as you can see on the tutorial,he clicked on the grease pencil white plane and the texture with a pre-determined size has been applied directly. This is also what I want to do with my facial texture. I want to click on the front part of the 3D character and boom : the front part of the facial texture will be applied to that. Is that possible ? Can u give me some suggestion to achieve the result ? thanks.

Comment: Grease Pencil isn't going to project any better than the current Stencil mapping mode, as it will actually not even place or project correctly at all. You might try using the older method of mapping this manually using a seam down the back of the model and unwrapping it and manually adjusting in the UV image editor.

Comment: is there another way for having different facial brushes to choose with located in some place of the blender 2.8 interface ?

Comment: Do you just need to have multiple textures in one brush? This is simple to do, but means an extra step. You can gather facial textures to use and put them in a directory, and rename them face.001, face.002 etc. so that you can use them as an image sequence as a brush texture, and then scrub the timeline to change them in the brush.